# BMP280 Level 5 Error

Tags: pi-zero-w-2

I have two of these units, one is working, the other throws this error

```
Error 5 performing I2C data transfer.Exception:System.IO.IOException: Error 5 performing I2C data transfer.
at System.Device.I2c.UnixI2cBus.WriteReadCore(UInt16 deviceAddress, Byte* writeBuffer, Byte* readBuffer, UInt16 writeBufferLength, UInt16 readBufferLength)   
at System.Device.I2c.UnixI2cBus.Write(Int32 deviceAddress, ReadOnlySpan`1 buffer)   
at System.Device.I2c.UnixI2cDevice.Write(ReadOnlySpan`1 buffer)   
at System.Device.I2c.UnixI2cDevice.WriteByte(Byte value)   
at Iot.Device.Bmxx80.Bmxx80Base..ctor(Byte deviceId, I2cDevice i2cDevice)   
at Iot.Device.Bmxx80.Bmx280Base..ctor(Byte deviceId, I2cDevice i2cDevice)   
at Iot.Device.Bmxx80.Bmp280..ctor(I2cDevice i2cDevice)   
at IOTEdgeModuel.ResourceAccess.TemperatureSensor_BMP280.Initialize() in
```

I have run i2cdetect and both respond the same.

Other than perhaps a manufacturing fault - Why would I get an Level 5 error?

Comment: error 5 is an IO error, given the fact that the device is successfully detected, it would suggest a faulty device

Comment: It was a bad solder job - even though I looked at that hard, I simply re-did it, and the device started working.  I'm learning, slowly, the difficulty if the bug is software or hardware.

Answer (score 0):

[Jaromanda](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/33057/jaromanda-x)

Was essentially correct, it was defective cause the solder job was not good enought!